# How do veth interfaces connect to each other on a linux box?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have been playing with Google Kubernetes Engine cluster recently. I have a question regarding their CNI. I have read from GCP documents and other articles that there is a bridge which all veth interfaces connect to. Basically, for each container, a veth pair is created.  One end of it is in container and the other end of it is connected to a bridge device.  When containers on the same node communicates with each other, packets exchange is using layer 2 bridge device.  This is also how GKE documentation describes.

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/network-overview#pods

https://medium.com/cloudzone/gke-networking-options-explained-demonstrated-5c0253415eba

I created a cluster on Google, I can see there is a bridge device docker0, but there is no interfaces associated with it.

```
gke-xxxxxxxxx /home/uuuuuuu # brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
docker0     8000.0242fd0b0cf4   no      
gke-xxxxxxxxxx /home/uuuuuuu #
```

Then I created a cluster using Virtualbox, I can see interfaces are associated with the bridge device.

```
[root@k8s-2 ~]# brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
cni0        8000.36dae477639c   no      veth7f6c1f01
                                        vethccd0d71d
                                        vethe63e4285
```

What I am trying to reason about is why I cannot find the bridge device on Google VMs?  Is there a special feature of Linux Kernel used in this scenario?

When I inspect each veth interface on Google VM, they all have the same ip address 10.188.2.1

```
gke-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /home/user.name # ifconfig
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.123.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 169.254.123.255
        ether 02:42:fd:0b:0c:f4  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1460
        inet 10.10.1.19  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::4001:aff:fe0a:113  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 42:01:0a:0a:01:13  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2192921  bytes 1682211226 (1.5 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1288701  bytes 468627202 (446.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 276348  bytes 153128345 (146.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 276348  bytes 153128345 (146.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth27cee774: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1460
        inet 10.188.2.1  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 10.188.2.1
        inet6 fe80::10b7:98ff:fe2f:2e08  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 12:b7:98:2f:2e:08  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 32  bytes 2306 (2.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10  bytes 710 (710.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth6eba4cdf: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1460
        inet 10.188.2.1  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 10.188.2.1
        inet6 fe80::c4e3:b0ff:fe5f:63da  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether c6:e3:b0:5f:63:da  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 537091  bytes 138245354 (131.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 477870  bytes 122515885 (116.8 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth8bcf1494: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1460
        inet 10.188.2.1  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 10.188.2.1
        inet6 fe80::70cb:c4ff:fe8c:a747  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 72:cb:c4:8c:a7:47  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 50  bytes 3455 (3.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 28  bytes 2842 (2.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethbb2135c7: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1460
        inet 10.188.2.1  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 10.188.2.1
        inet6 fe80::1469:daff:fea0:8b5b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 16:69:da:a0:8b:5b  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 223995  bytes 82725559 (78.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 239258  bytes 60203574 (57.4 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vetheee4e8e3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1460
        inet 10.188.2.1  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 10.188.2.1
        inet6 fe80::ec6c:3bff:fef3:70c2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ee:6c:3b:f3:70:c2  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 311669  bytes 40562747 (38.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 304461  bytes 628195110 (599.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

What is behind these veth interfaces?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Doesn't the 2nd document you linked explain it? "With Calico, there is no L2 network bridge in the node, and instead, L3 routing is used for all traffic between pods"

Comment: Thanks Mark.  If you see my example, all interfaces are prefixed with veth instead of cali.  My cluster doesn't use calico CNI.

Comment: If you want to look at packets flowing from/to the pod cidr, specify cbr0, which is the Linux bridge that has all the veth interfaces connected to all the containers. Using `tcpdump -i cbr0` might help with the troubleshooting.

Comment: @AlexG It doesn't look cbr0 exists.  I can only see veth interfaces, but not the bridge device which is a mystery.
Anyways, what I found out is cbr0 does exist if I use an older version.  I tried 1.18-gke version.  This version uses docker as container runtime and it has the cbr0 device.  Starting 1.19.x-gke-xxxx, GKE nodes use containerd as the runtime and cbr0 device is no longer created.

Answer (score 1):

If the bridge already has interfaces, The `brctl show` command can be used to view a node's bridge and interface details. It appears that you haven't introduced any interfaces to the bridge in your situation. You can add interfaces to the bridge with `sudo brctl addif docker0 veth0`, and you can receive all essential bridge and interface details in a node with the same command. Check [this document](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/gke-networking-fundamentals) for reference.

Comment: With a fully working cluster, it is unnecessary to add the veth0 to the docker0.  This is already handled when a new pod is created.  As I mentioned in the above comment, 1.18-gke is the last version which still uses cbr0.  I believe the routing of packets is done by routing rules.  In 1.19.x, every pod IP has its own route table entry.

Comment: Are there pods that has set `hostNetwork` to false on your GKE 1.19?